# Prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{|z_{k}|^2}{|z_{k+1}-z_{k}|^2}\ge 1$ for complex numbers $z_k$'s

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Let $n \geq 3$. Let $z_{i}$ (for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$) be complex numbers. Assume that $z_{k+1} - z_k \ne 0$ for $k=1,2, \cdots, n-1$ and $z_n  - z_1 \ne 0$. Show that
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{|z_{k}|^2}{|z_{k+1}-z_{k}|^2}\ge 1\tag{1},$$
>
> where $z_{n+1}=z_{1}$.

I think can use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to solve it. But I think this complex inequality can't hold:

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}|z_{k}|\right)^2\ge \sum_{k=1}^{n}|z_{k+1}-z_{k}|^2.$$

So how do I prove $(1)$?

Comment: I don't think the inequality you have at the bottom holds. Consider $n=2, z_1 = 1, z_2 = 0$.

Comment: In any case, it is not at all related with the original inequality, as the quotient of the sums is not the sum of the quotients.

Comment: @mathworker21, $n\ge 3$....

Comment: @functionsug: $n=3$, $z_1=1$, $z_2=z_3=0$.

Comment: the $ |z_{2}-z_{3}|\neq 0$

Comment: $n=3$, $z_1=1$, $z_2=0.1$, $z_3=0$. In any case, as I already mentioned, the second inequality has absolutely no relation with the first one.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I wouldn't be so assertive. The second inequality (when it holds) implies the first one. Still, you are right: the second inequality can fail very easily, so this implication is rather useless. I fancy I can prove (1) for $n\ge 4$, but $n=3$ looks harder.

Answer (score 5):

Let's try to do $n\ge 4$ at least. Let $x_k=|z_k|$. Then it will suffice to show that 
$$
\Phi(x)=\sum_k\frac{x_k^2}{(x_k+x_{k+1})^2}\ge 1
$$
Let us consider $\Phi$ on $x_k>0,\sum_k x_k=1$.

Notice first of all that if $\Phi(x)\le m<1$, then $x$ is separated from the boundary in the sense that $x_k\ge c(m)>0$ for all $k$. Indeed, at least one $x_k\ge 1/n$. Since $m<1$, we must have $x_{k+1}\ge\lambda(m)x_k$ (otherwise one single term is already above $m$. Then $x_{k+2}\ge\lambda(m)x_{k+1}$ and so on over the cycle, so all $x_j\ge n^{-1}\lambda(m)^{n-1}$. Thus, only the critical points are of interest. Also, since the functional is homogeneous of degree $0$, the differential should vanish at the critical points on the whole space, not just along the hyperplane $\sum_k dx_k=0$.

Now, 
$$
x_{k}\frac{\partial \Phi(x)}{\partial x_k}=2\left[-\frac{x_{k-1}^2x_k}{(x_{k-1}+x_{k})^3}+\frac{x_{k}^2x_{k+1}}{(x_{k}+x_{k+1})^3}\right]
$$
which means that at any critical point all ratios $w_k=\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}$ are roots of $(1+w)^3=sw$ with some common $s>0$.

Now comes some casework. Notice that this equation can have only two positive roots (the LHS is strictly convex). When $s=8$, $w=1$ is a root and it is the *larger* one (because the tangent line to $(1+w)^3$ at $w=1$ has slope $12>8$. Thus, when $s<8$, both roots are below $1$, which makes this case impossible because then $x_k$ would decrease over the cycle. When $s=8$, the only option is to have all $w_k=1$, which results in $\Phi(x)=\frac n4\ge 1$ as long as $n\ge 4$. So the only interesting case is $s>8$ when there are two roots $y<1<z$. Notice that we cannot use $z$ every time (there are no strictly increasing cycles). If we use $y$ at least once, we have
$$
\Phi(x)\ge \frac{1}{(1+y)^2}+\frac{n-1}{(1+z)^2}
=
\frac{1}{(1+y)^2}+\frac{(n-1)(1+z)}{(1+z)^3}
\\ \ge
\frac{1}{(1+y)^2}+\frac{3z}{(1+z)^3}=\frac{1}{(1+y)^2}+\frac 3s\,.
$$
If we show that the last expression is above $1$, we are done.

To this end, it will suffice to show that $(1+y)^3<sy$ for $y=\sqrt{\frac s{s-3}}-1$ (the value that makes the expression  we are interested in exactly $1$. This rewrites as
$$
s\left(\sqrt{\frac s{s-3}}-1\right)>\sqrt{\frac s{s-3}}^3\,,
$$
then
$$
\left(s-\frac s{s-3}\right)\sqrt{\frac s{s-3}}>s
$$
and, denoting $t=\frac 1{s-3}<\frac 15$,
$$
(1-t)\sqrt{1+3t}> 1\,,
$$
or, finally,
$$
(1-t)^2(1+3t)=1+t-5t^2+3t^3> 1\,,
$$
which is obvious for $0<t<\frac 15$.

Comment: Interesting. Your inequality (upon substituting $a_k = x_{k+1}/x_k$) rewrites as: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\left(1+a_k\right)^2} \geq 1$ where $n \geq 4$ and where $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ are positive reals satisfying $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n = 1$. This should be a rather well-known one, methinks, and I'm even thinking I might have seen it in one of the canonical places (such as Vasile Cirtoaje's book). Mixing variables is the first tactic that comes to my mind, seeing that the function $x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{\left(1+e^x\right)^2}$ is convex starting at $x = \ln \dfrac12$.

Comment: That function is convex on $(-\ln 2, \infty)$ and is concave on $(-\infty, -\ln 2)$. Based on this fact, it is not hard to prove the inequality.

Answer (score 4):

Not a proof, but here are some ideas.

Note that if $z_k=0$ for any $k$, the inequality holds trivially. So we may assume $z_k\ne0$ for all $k$. Then, 
$$\tag1
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{|z_{k}|^2}{|z_{k+1}-z_{k}|^2}
=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{|\frac{z_{k+1}}{z_{k}}-1|^2}.
$$
Thus the inequality may be rewritten as 
$$\tag2
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{|\alpha_{k}-1|^2}\ge 1,
$$
where $\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_n=1$.

If $|\alpha_k-1|<1$ for any $k$, then $(2)$ holds trivially. So we may further assume that $|\alpha_k-1|\geq1$ for all $k$.

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/q/615968/42969 looks similar, perhaps it can be used here.

Comment: How is $\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_n=1$ ?

Comment: Write it down, and use that $z_{n+1}=z_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. First any two consecutive terms must be different otherwise it leads to division by zero. Next 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{|z_k|^2}{|z_{k+1}-z_k|^2}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{|z_{k+1}-(z_{k+1}-z_k)|^2}{|z_{k+1}-z_k|^2}\geqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{||z_{k+1}|-|z_{k+1}-z_k||^2}{|z_{k+1}-z_k|^2}$$
by triangle inequality. The last sum is equivalent to
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{||z_{k+1}|-|z_{k+1}-z_k||^2}{|z_{k+1}-z_k|^2}=\sum_{k=1}^n\Big(\frac{|z_{k+1}|}{|z_{k+1}-z_k|}-1\Big)^2$$
Therefore it is sufficient to prove the inequality
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\Big(\frac{|z_{k+1}|}{|z_{k+1}-z_k|}-1\Big)^2\geqslant 1$$
If this is not the case then for all $k$ we must have 
$|z_{k+1}|<2|z_{k+1}-z_k|$. Maybe this could lead to some contradictions using also $z_{n+1}=z_1$.

Comment: Isn't what you suggest as “sufficient to prove”  a *stronger* inequality? Why should that be easier?

Comment: @MartinR yes it is a stronger inequality that is why it is sufficient. I am not claiming it is easier, but it could be. I don't know for sure, this is just a suggestion.

Comment: Your sufficient inequality fails for $\left(z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n\right) = \left(1,4,2\right)$.